# First character of std::cout cut off after a while (std::cin << num), fix?

Tags: c++, io, git-bash

I am running an example in the book, *C++ Primer* by Stanley B Lippman, in 1.4.1:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    // Read until end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read.
    std::cout << "Enter values: "; std::cout.flush();
    while (std::cin >> value)
    {
        sum += value;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am running it with the most recent GNU compiler. After entering values, I press *CTRL + ALT + D* on git bash. Although everything seems in order, the `std::cin` seems to consume the "S" in "Sum is:" in the output.

```
Enter values: 5 4 3
um is: 12
```

An obvious solution is to add a `std::cout << "l"; std::cout.flush();` directly after the `while` loop but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't make me type nonsensical code.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your terminal or shell or similar, not with the C++ program: standard input and standard output are separate file descriptors, streams, etc., so it's unlikely the character is moving from output to input. I'm not familiar with git bash, but on most Unix-like terminals, I would type Ctrl-D, not Ctrl-Alt-D, to signal an end-of-input.

Comment: Can't reproduce.   From the description, it is not a C++ problem - it will be related to how your host environment (terminal, shell, bash, etc) interacts with your program.   Or, more specifically, how they interact with buffering of input and output streams.    The fix therefore won't be in your program.   It will be in settings of your host environment.

Comment: [Nothing wrong with the code.](https://ideone.com/OxzYeV). I think your terminal may be gaslighting you.

Comment: This marks the end of my Git Bash usage. Thank you!

Comment: I have git bash installed, so I tried. And as expected, it works. `Enter values: 5 4 3 ^D`, `Sum is: 12`.

Comment: @Zereges Maybe it's because I'm using Git Bash on Windows. I believe that is the reason I must use Ctrl-Alt-D and cannot use Ctrl-Z or Ctrl-D to signal end-of-file.

Comment: @LucasMcMasteur I am using Git Bash on Windows too and Ctrl+D (or Ctrl+Z) works for me.